# Reversing a refactor in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I was asked to do a name change and to maintain consistency, I refactored several classes to change their names. Now, the boss has decided he's a bit nervous about all this and just wants me to forget the name change altogether. But, I've already refactored my code, although I haven't committed it to CVS. Is there any way to get Eclipse to reverse the refactoring so I don't have to just grab the last committed code? I can't find a way to get Eclipse and CVS to work together to pull back the original code with the original names.

Thanks.

Comment: How many classes did you change? Wouldn't it be trivial to just refactor again?

Comment: Again refactor with previous name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:

1. Refactor to previous name.
2. Perform CVS update to get CVS to see files as not changed.

This may not be 100% perfect due to formatting differences, but it should be close.

Option 2:

Use this if you don't have other outstanding changes besides refactoring.

Right-click on the project and select Replace With -> Latest From [whatever]...

Comment: Thanks, Konstantin, I'll see if we can get Option 2 to work. Option 1 isn't really an option because I would still have to check in all the re-refactored code, right? It's checking in all that code that has my (non-technical) boss worried.

Comment: Note that for Option 1, step 2 will erase most if not all changes from re-refactoring. CVS would go back to no change state for those files.

Comment: Ah, I understand better now. That might be an option after all. Thank you!